# Get number of records with SQL while using LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to implement pages into my webpage. I have got it so that a user can put the page number they want into the url bar that they want to go to. I did this by using that number in the URL bar and multiplying it by 10 for the `OFFSET` parameter in the SQL statement to get 10 records for each page.

But i need to know how many records that could be returned by that SQL statement if i removed the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` parameters. Is this possible within the SQL statement or will i have to request every record from the database and count the length on every page? thanks.

EDIT:

I want the amount of records that this statement COULD return if i didn't use LIMIT or OFFSET

```
SELECT nfc_film.*, nfc_category.name FROM nfc_film
        JOIN nfc_film_category
          ON nfc_film.film_id = nfc_film_category.film_id
        JOIN nfc_category
          ON nfc_category.category_id = nfc_film_category.category_id
        WHERE title
          LIKE :searchterm OR nfc_category.name = :category
        LIMIT 10
        OFFSET :page
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (LIMIT isn't standard SQL.)

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable;` ?

Comment: @jarlh im using an sqlite database and PHP PDO.

Comment: you can't get this info from within the same query which uses the LIMIT/OFFSET keywords, no...that query just returns the records you asked for. You can run a _separate_ query like the one Cid quoted above, to get that info.

Comment: The amount of records will be, at most, the value set for `LIMIT`

Comment: @Cid So there isn't a way to do it without executing twice as many queries each time?

Comment: @AdamCole no, the query is the query. It will return as many records as it returns. If you want to know how many records would be returned without LIMIT and OFFSET, that is a different query. To know its result, you have to run that query (or a version of it which selects the COUNT instead of returning rows, but with the same criteria). Each query is independent. Adding something like LIMIT doesn't make it a "different version of the same query", it's just a different query, full stop. The two have no relationship to each other, as far as the DBMS is concerned.

Comment: Bear in mind also, the result of the same query can of course change from moment to moment between each time it's executed, as people modify the database records. So even if you write on your web page "displaying records 100-110 of 2000 total records" (I assume this is why you're asking?), the next minute that could be 2020 total records, or 1975 total records, or whatever, as the database changes. (Of course if you don't update your data very often, it's less of a concern, but the point still stands)

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results is good reading on this topic, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of rows returned by the current query, since you tagged php with PDO, you can use [`fetchAll()`](https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) along with [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

In example :

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("<your query>");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll();
$numberOfRows = count($result);
```

---

To get the **total** number of rows of your table, but still using `LIMIT`, you can either

Count that in a separate query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM nfc_film
JOIN nfc_film_category
ON nfc_film.film_id = nfc_film_category.film_id
JOIN nfc_category
ON nfc_category.category_id = nfc_film_category.category_id
WHERE title LIKE :searchterm OR nfc_category.name = :category;
```

Or do it in a single query, using a `GROUP BY` (this will prevent you the bad practice to use a `*`)

```
--                          v------------- Random datas ------------------------v
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Count", nfc_film.id, nfc_film.name, nfc_film.otherInformation, nfc_category.name FROM nfc_film
JOIN nfc_film_category
ON nfc_film.film_id = nfc_film_category.film_id
JOIN nfc_category
ON nfc_category.category_id = nfc_film_category.category_id
WHERE title
LIKE :searchterm OR nfc_category.name = :category
GROUP BY nfc_film.id, nfc_film.name, nfc_film.otherInformation, nfc_category.name
LIMIT 10
OFFSET :page
```